# OpenLayers - Avoid selecting overlapping lines on modifying MultiLineString

Tags: openlayers

I want to be able to modify lines inside the multilinestring feature. But I when I try to modify multilinestring and if there is overlapping points, openlayers moves intersected lines all together.

How can I avoid this situation and modify only selected line in multilinestring feature?

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { defaults as defaultInteractions, Modify, Select } from 'ol/interaction';
import { GeoJSON } from 'ol/format';

const GeoJSONDataUrl = 'dist/data.json';
const raster = new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() });
const reader = new GeoJSON();
const source = new VectorSource({ wrapX: false });
const vector = new VectorLayer({ source: source });
const select = new Select({ layers: [vector], multi: true });
const modify = new Modify({
    features: select.getFeatures(),
  }
);

console.log('multi true');

const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([select, modify]),
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});

fetch(GeoJSONDataUrl)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    const features = reader.readFeatures(res, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
    source.addFeatures(features);
    map.getView().fit(features[0].getGeometry().getExtent());
  })
```

Here is an example gif:
[image]

Comment: The reason fro this behavior is option `multi: true` in `Select` interaction.

Comment: @TomazicM thank you for your reply, I tried but didn't get any result. I assume multi works only for multiple features

Comment: You have to remove this option.

Comment: I set it false @TomazicM

Comment: If that is a single self-intersecting line with a vertex at the intersection point that is expected behaviour.  If there is no vertex at the intersection you could set an `insertVertexCondition` on the modify interaction to avoid creating a new one.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Mike but all I want is that select one line at a time, I just don't want to select below line

Comment: I think you must have a shared vertex at the intersection as without a snap option it is difficult to create a new vertex on both parts of the line.  If the geometry is a MultiLineString and you need to edit each component LineString independently you would need to create new LineString features for each part.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Mike, if I spare lines in the multi lime string and add them as individual feature and it would fall a part in during modification. I would like to keep integrity of the whole line

Comment: In that case you must not allow vertices at the point of self-intersection in your geometry. You could use turf https://turfjs.org/docs/#kinks to identify self-intersects and if any of those points match one or more coordinates in the geometry the coordinates must be removed.